# Extracting data from RingCentral call log API using azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, ringcentral

Has anyone had any experience accessing the RingCentral API using Azure data factory? I need to pull data from the below API to store in our data warehouse but I am finding very little online about how to achieve this.

https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Log/readCompanyCallLog

I have gone down the route of creating a REST-linked service and filling in the Auth2 fields but I get the below error.

I also found this article which explained how to get data from the API using a data factory but it is very vague and mentions creating a web activity first to get the authentication token.

https://medium.com/ringcentral-developers/low-code-integration-of-ringcentral-analytics-api-with-microsoft-azure-power-bi-2a400fa7a15f

Apologies if I am missing something obvious here, it just doesn't seem like there are many straightforward guides on how to achieve this.. and I am quite new when it comes to using APIs.

Appreciate any suggestions/similar experiences!

[image]